# Deploying Django

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, django

When finding web hosting for Rails apps, the hoster must have support for ruby on rails -- that is evident.  What about hosting for Django?  What support does the hoster need to provide?  Python, or more than just Python?

This might seem like an obvious question, but I'm new to web development frameworks so I must ask :)

Comment: It seems that python is all that's needed...making it easier to deploy than Rails apps :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It just needs to support Python 2.3 or later (but not 3.0, yet), preferably with `mod_wsgi` support (although it also works with [a bunch of other options](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/ServerArrangements), if required).

Answer (score 3):

Technically, as other responders say, the host needs very little (hey, Django even runs with Google app engine for all the latter's limitations!-).  But if you want a little bit more (as in, say, *support* for any issues you might encounter!), I suggest you read [this site](http://djangohosting.org/) as well -- it will take you but a short time, and it may prove to be really useful info.

Answer (score 3):

Other responses have covered the technical question, but it should also be mentioned that [djangofriendly.com](http://djangofriendly.com) is an invaluable resource for selecting a Django web host.

Answer (score 2):

Python is all that is needed.

I think there is a cPanel plugin which allows your users to create and deploy Django applications, so if you have a VPS or Reseller account, or your host is running cPanel, you could simply tell them to install it. If I find the link to the plugin I will post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Python is **not** the *only* thing need **if you run a dedicated server**.

You need(please correct me if I'm missing something):

- A webserver which will communicate
  with your Django web application,
  e.g.: Apache with mod_wsgi.
- A database interface, such as MySQL or PostgreSQL (just to mention some popular).
- Python.
- (Dependencies, Libraries, etc.)

You may want to read [this](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/ServerArrangements) or [some general resources](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoResources#CheatSheetsandQuickStarts)

**If you use some hosting service**, then you'll probably need to find a provider who claims to be able to run Django ;)